# Display problems in java, can't find symbol errors

Tags: java

Keep getting these cannot find symbol errors. I know its concerning the picture class and it's methods but I know they are there but my compiler can't recognize them. Any Ideas?

```
     import java.awt.Color;
     import java.awt.Graphics;

     public class DispTest 
     { 

       private Picture display;
       private Graphics graphics;

       public DispTest()
       {
        display = new Picture(500,500);
        graphics = display.getGraphics();
        for(int x = 0; x < display.getWidth(); x++) {
           for(int y = 0; y < display.getHeight(); y++) {
             display.getPixel(x,y).setColor(new Color(123,204,246));
             if((x > 0 && x % 50 == 0) || (y > 0 && y % 50 == 0))
             display.getPixel(x,y).setColor(new Color(44,72,39));
           }
        }

        graphics.setColor(new Color(44,72,39));
          for(int x = 10; x < display.getWidth(); x += 50) 
             for(int y = 10; y < display.getHeight(); y += 50) 
                graphics.drawOval(x,y,30,30);
           display.show();
        }


        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
          DispTest dt = new DispTest();

        }
    }
```

5 errors found:

```
File: C:\Users\Andrew\SoftwareDevelopment\DispTest.java  [line: 22]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getGraphics()
  location: variable display of type Picture
File: C:\Users\Andrew\SoftwareDevelopment\DispTest.java  [line: 25]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPixel(int,int)
  location: variable display of type Picture
File: C:\Users\Andrew\SoftwareDevelopment\DispTest.java  [line: 27]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPixel(int,int)
  location: variable display of type Picture
File: C:\Users\Andrew\SoftwareDevelopment\DispTest.java  [line: 32]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getWidth()
  location: variable display of type Picture
File: C:\Users\Andrew\SoftwareDevelopment\DispTest.java  [line: 33]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getHeight()
  location: variable display of type Picture
```

Comment: What do you mean "I know the picture class is there"? Where are they? I assume this is a class you wrote. Did you compile Picture.java before compiling this one?

Comment: I believe the picture class is included in awt but not sure.

Comment: Check the available awt classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html).

Comment: ^^ There's no _Picture_ class on that page.... How on earth have you written this much code using a class that doesn't even exist!!?!  I guess we'll have to assume you found this code somewhere and don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Thank you scott and Voicu. Not you Jahroy, youre useless.

Comment: @AndrewLangford - Thanks for wasting everyone's time. You tell me I'm useless, yet you're the one who _assumes_ a random class is part of a package, then posts a question on StackOverflow without bothering to look it up.  Good luck to you!  And... my statement is true: **There is no Picture class in AWT**.  So... I'm not useless.  I just told you what is wrong with your code (again).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `Picture` supposed to be the [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) class, with the `import java.awt.Image;` added on top of your class? An IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans) would have helped you in this case.

So you can have:

```
// import
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

...

// declaration
private Image display;

...

// instantiation, feel free to choose your third argument from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html
display = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Comment: There is no _getPixel()_ method for the Image class.  All we can do is guess where this magical _Picture_ class came from in the OP's code.  Obviously the OP has no clue either...

Comment: True, but he can probably use the `setRGB` method from [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to color pixels.

Comment: There's no doubt that he has countless options...  One thing that is not an option is to use a random class for which he has no source code or class files!

Comment: The method I mentioned fits with the example given in the answer and it doesn't deviate much from what he was trying to do though.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `.class` files and re-compile your code. This error occurs when your `.class` files are from an older version of your source.

Comment: I deleted them and got down to only two errors. So when I create a new Picture class display it can't find the picture class, but isn't that included inside awt.*?

Comment: There's an `Image` class?

Comment: @Andrew: Either way, you're not doing a wildcard (*) import, so it won't be picked.

Comment: I added the awt wildcard but still getting the same errors.

Comment: There is no Picture class in Awt... Not sure how you've gotten this far writing code for a class that doesn't exist!